# Subplot 3 graph in one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am Having trouble with the last subplot. The last Crosstab plot appears by itself, and then the subplot has the first 2 subplots but the 3rd one is empty and contains no data. How can I graph it so that all 3 graphs come up in one figure and they share they same Y axis or 'Frequency'

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from patsy import dmatrices
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score

#Data Exploration
data = sm.datasets.fair.load_pandas().data
data['affair'] = np.where(data['affairs'] > 0 , 1,0)
print(data)
print(data.groupby('affair').mean())
print(data.groupby('rate_marriage').mean())

plt.subplot(331)
data['educ'].hist()
plt.title('Histogram of Education')
plt.xlabel('Education Level')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.subplot(332)
data['rate_marriage'].hist()
plt.title('Histogram of Marriage Rating')
plt.xlabel('Marriage Rating')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.subplot(333)
pd.crosstab(data['rate_marriage'], data['affair'].astype(bool)).plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('Marriage Rating distribution by affair Status')
plt.xlabel('Marriage Rating')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

[image: This is the subplot with the blank data]

[image: This is what should be in the subplot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the pandas plotting function where to plot the data.
This can be achieved through the `ax` keyword.

```
ax= plt.subplot(333)
pd.crosstab(data['rate_marriage'], data['affair'].astype(bool)).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
```